# How to enable zip.dll in elementor

Tags: wordpress, xampp, elementor

I'am totally a newbee.
I look on the internet and follow several solutions but it doesn't works.
I changed the php.ini, add extension=zip i deleted ; and did the same for extension=GD.
I also put a new extension --> extension=php_zip.dll

but it doens't works for wordpress template kits.
On the system info of elementor i get
[system info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkmJ7.png)

who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I uninstalled everything and started again with a clean sheet.

It works.